# Variable as name of row in TWIG : Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem in my Symfony2 application. In Controller I'm getting an array of facebook users and posting it to my form class, where I create some checkboxes. In my template I need to print theese checkboxes as pictures of these users. I try to print it like this : {{form_row(form.{{girl.id}})}}, but TWIG template doesn't allow to use variable {{girl.id}} as name of row and also I don't know how print theese checkboxes as pictures. Can anyone help me with this ?

This is ma Controller action

```
public function indexAction()
    {

        $facebook = $this->get('facebook');
        $friends = $facebook->api('me/friends?fields=id,name,gender');

        $friends = $friends['data'];
        foreach($friends as $friend){

            if(array_key_exists('gender',$friend))
            {
            if($friend['gender'] =='female')
                $girls[]=$friend;
            }
            }
            for ($i=0; $i <5; $i++) { 
                $default[]=$girls[$i];
            }
        $formular = new FriendsForm();
        $formular->addFriend($default);

        $form = $this->createForm($formular);




        return array('girls'=>$default,'form' => $form->createView());
    }
```

This is my Form class

```
class FriendsForm extends AbstractType
{
    private $friends;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $friends = $this->friends;

        foreach($friends as $friend)
        {
            $builder
            ->add($friend['id'],'checkbox',array('label' => false,'required'=>false, 'value'=>$friend['']));
        ;    
        }

    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return '';

    }

     public function addFriend($data)
    {
        $this->friends = $data;
    }

}
```

This is my template

```
<p>
{%if girls is defined%}
{{form_start(form)}}
{%for girl in girls%}
{{form.row(form.{{girl.id}})}}
{%endfor%}
{{form_end(form)}}
{%endif%}
</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `attribute` built-in function (as of 1.2).

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html says

> attribute can be used to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable

In such case you can write like below:

```
{{ form_row(attribute(form, girl.id)) }}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot man it works. But you have one little mistake in code. It is not form.row , but form_row .

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as

```
{{form.row(form[girl.id])}}
```

Comment: Correct but it's misspelled (dot instead of an underscore). It's: `{{ form_row(form[girl.id]) }}`