# Twig multiple use of attribute()

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Trying to parametrize the name of a form element in Twig…

No problem, if the *first* part of the name is to be parametrized,
as already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611010/variable-as-name-of-row-in-twig-symfony-2).
But if it sits **in the middle**, it won't work, since twig tries to access the `attribute` of `formElement`.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{{ form_row(formElement.attribute(_context, whatever).someAttribute) }}
```

Any tips welcome. Thx in advance.

Comment: Sorry. The title is not _that_ correct any longer, since I tried to describe the problem with an example as simple as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Have you tried this ? 

{{ form_row(form.formelement, {'attr': {'name': 'foo'}}) }}

Comment: @Mintho433 Thanks for your response.I need to render a form row by its name. Business as usual. But the name itself is dynamic. I need to have the middle part (`part2`) of the name parametrized: **name = part1.part2.part3**.

Answer (score 0):

`attribute()` works like [this](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) :

```
{{ attribute(array, item) }}
```

So if in `part1.part2.part3`, you want to parametrize `part2`, then I think you need this simple statement :

```
{% set name =  attribute(part1, part2).part3  %}
```